# montecarlo procedure in rstudio

Tags: r, montecarlo, integral

Using a Monte-Carlo procedure, obtained an estimate and a confidence interval (95%) of the following quantities:

- The integral of f (x) = a + 10x ^ 2-x ^ 3 for x between a and b
- The probability that X + Y> 0.3 * a * b, where X is a Gaussian variable of mean 0 and variance b, while Y is an exponential average variable a.

The numbers a and b are [2.5,4.5].
I have tried so:

```
a= 2.5
b= 4.5
N=10^5

x= rnorm(mean=0, sd= sqrt(b))
hist(x)
y= exp(mean=a)
hist(y)
Z=rnorm(mean=0, sd= sqrt(b)) + exp(mean=a)
P(x+y)>0.3*a*b
```

Comment: someone can help me make the r code?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve what appears to be your homework?

Comment: I tried to do this but I don't know if it's correct:                                                        a= 2.5
b= 4.5
N=10^5

x= rnorm(mean=0, sd= sqrt(b))
hist(x)
y= exp(mean=a)
hist(y)
Z=rnorm(mean=0, sd= sqrt(b)) + exp(mean=a)
P(x+y)>0.3*a*b

Comment: @Maurizio Hi and welcome. Please add the code you just posted in your question. It'll be easier for people coming here.